# How do I make the performance trend visible/available on Jenkins when using jmeter-maven-plugin for running the jmeter tests?

Tags: jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-plugin, jmeter-maven-plugin

Not sure if this is a common case... I couldn't find something this specific, so here I am. I'm in a situation where I don't have the Performance plug-in fully enabled in the Jenkins box I'm running my tests in, so I'm using the jmeter-maven-plugin for running the JMeter tests and I intend to use the (Jenkins) performance plug-in for showing the results on the job page.

I believe I should do something like this...
[image]

Another problem is that (of course) the file name the plugin generates is not fixed (yyyymmdd is prepended).

The file goes to a path like this, in this format... and I don't think that's where the Performance plug-in will be looking for it:

```
myjavaproject/myjenkinsjob/target/jmeter/results/20180406-report.csv
```

How do I achieve that, IF I do somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) in order to publish [JMeter aggregate report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) and response graph in Jenkins.

Additionally, you can try [Redline13](https://www.redline13.com) for [Continuous Performance](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/03/continuous-performance/) testing as it provides integration with Jenkins and will help you to keep your performance testing report on a single platform.